# opencv find distance for every pixel in image from certain point?

Tags: numpy, opencv

I have white-black image,and i want to find euclidean distance  for every white pixel to some point.

```
def remove_pixel(img,point,distance ):
  rimg=np.copy(img)
  for i in range(rimg.shape[0]):
    for j in range(rimg.shape[1]):
      if rimg[i,j]==1 and distance((i,j),point)<distance:
        rimg[i,j]=0
  return rimg
```

How I can do this with out using loops?

Comment: distanceTransform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could vectorize your function by using [`numpy.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html?highlight=indices#numpy.indices) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def remove_pixel(img, point, distance):
    rows, cols = np.indices(img.shape)
    mask = (rows - point[0])**2 + (cols - point[1])**2 < distance**2
    return np.where(mask, 0, img)
```

#### Demo

```py
In [36]: from skimage.data import checkerboard

In [37]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [38]: img = checkerboard()

In [39]: out = remove_pixel(img, [75, 75], 50)

In [40]: fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    ...: ax0.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    ...: ax0.axis('off')
    ...: ax0.set_title('img')
    ...: ax1.imshow(out, cmap='gray')
    ...: ax1.axis('off')
    ...: ax1.set_title('out')
    ...: plt.show(fig)
```

[image: Results]